# how to create simple schedule chart with highchart

Tags: highcharts

How do I create a simple chart with a single horizontal bar. Xaxis is time and yaxis is one category named execution. I want to show a chart that shows a bar during the times when I have state executing and for states in between I want to display a blank in the same horizontal bar.

Comment: You should take a look Highcharts demos, then click `view options`. Have fun.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for, I think, is a Gantt chart. Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/KNGba/. It is a basic chart with just one element. Now check out this one: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/r6emu/. This shows you events during a time line.